# minimizing this expression: $\frac{(x+y)(c+d)-(z+w)(a+b)}{(a+b)(c+d)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, percentages

Jody and Shelli each receive a box of buttons on Saturday and on Sunday.  Each button is either red or white, and the number of buttons in each of the four boxes is from $1$ to $100$, inclusive.

On both days, the percentage of red buttons in Jody's box is greater than the percentage of red buttons in Shelli's box.  If $J \%$ of Jody's total number of buttons are red and $S \%$ of Shelli's total number of buttons are red, what is the least possible value of $J-S$?  Express your answer to the nearest integer.

Ans. -96  (Source:  2021 MathCounts Target Round, calculators allowed)

I had Jody receiving on Saturday and Sunday respectively $a$ and $b$ buttons of which $x$ and $y$ are red.  Shelli on Saturday and Sunday receive respectively $c$ and $d$ buttons, of which $z$ and $w$ are red.

We have $\frac{x}{a} > \frac{z}{c}$ and  $\frac{y}{b} > \frac{w}{d}$ and

$J-S=100 \cdot (\frac{x+y}{a+b} - \frac{z+w}{c+d})$.  So,

$J-S=100 \cdot \frac{(x+y)(c+d)-(z+w)(a+b)}{(a+b)(c+d)}$

I'm not sure how to minimize this expression.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use descriptive titles. "math contest question" is way too broad. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: With respect to contest math, it is crucial that you include the source of the question, and date of the competition.

Comment: Also, please use a title relating to the specific mathematics question you have.  You've already informed us the question is related to contest-math, via the appropriate tag you chose.  Focus your question title on the specific issue you do not understand. "How to simplify the equation $J-S=100 \cdot \frac{(x+y)(c+d)-(z+w)(a+b)}{(a+b)(c+d)}$?", for example.  (Also, explicitly define, in your post, what J and S, respectively, mean.)

Comment: This “-96” percentage figure doesn’t seem possible? It would be possible if J = number of Jody’s red buttons and S = number of Shelli’s red buttons instead

Comment: @BenjaminWang It is possible for the percentages. For the raw number, it could be even lower.

Comment: @Calvin Lin How do you do it? To make -96, you're allowed a maximum of J% = 4%, so maximum 8 reds for Jody. I tried a few things and there seems to be a contradiction somewhere :(

Comment: @BenjaminWang $J \approx 2%, S \approx 98%.   (I'm not quite certain how Jean's hint helps. I don't have a quick proof that it is the max, def not in time to buzz in confidently).

Answer (score 2):

("guessing from extreme scenarios" Approach for competitions that only needs final answer. It's most likely true, but isn't proven. )
For the first day, Jody has 1 red button (100%), Sheeli has 99 red buttons and 1 white button (99%).
For the second day, Jody has 1 red button and 99 white buttons (1%), Sheeli has 1 white button (0%).
Then, $ J = \frac{ 1 + 1 } { 1 + 100 } = 2/ 100$ and $ s = \frac{99+0 } { 100 + 1 } = 99 / 101.$
This gives us $2 / 101 - 99/101 \approx -96\%$.

---

Now, prove it.

Comment: Thank you @Calvin Lin.  I can't prove it, but it seems like for $J$, we want to minimize the #Red buttons, so he receives 1 button each day.  We also want to maximize the number of red buttons That Shelli receives, so give her $99$ buttons one day, which means Jody won't have any white buttons on Sat.  We also want Jody to have a large number of white buttons, so give him 99 white buttons on Sunday, which forces Shelli to have $0$ red buttons on Sunday.  Does that sound like a good explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Heuristic: use a graphical reasoning on the percentages transformed into slopes of the diagonals in these parallelograms:

[image]

(in fact, take a grid $200 \times 200$).

Comment: Thank you, @Jean.  So in comparing the slopes, it looks like we want to maximize $z$, $w$, $a$, and $b$ and minimize $x$, $y$, $c$, and $d$, while keeping $x<a$, $z<c$, $y<b$, and $w<d$, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: @Jean Marie it's minimising J-S, not minimising the absolute value of J-S

Comment: @Benjamin Wang Thanks !

Comment: Here is a photo of the original problem statement.  https://photos.app.goo.gl/mHByrXMSUsR7fCmZA

Comment: I'm thinking my strategy should be to minimize the number of buttons Jody receives while still having a greater fraction of red.  So maybe $x=1$, $a=2$ and $z=49$ and $c=50$ on Saturday.  And $y=1$, $b=2$, $w=49$, and $d=50$ on Sunday.  This gives $J-S=-48$.

Comment: @JeanMarie The minimum is $ - 96 \%$ (you're missing the negative sign).

Comment: @user1604149 Some assumptions of yours to question 1) Why not $ x = 1, a = 1$? 2) Why "minimize the number of buttons"?

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thanks !